# Сохранение стека переходов назад

Tags: android

Официальная документация гласит:

> Если пользователь выходит из задачи на длительное время, система удаляет из задачи все операции, кроме корневой операции. Когда пользователь возвращается в задачу, восстанавливается только корневая операция. Система ведет себя таким образом, так как после продолжительного времени пользователи обычно уже забросили то, чем они занимались ранее, и возвращаются в задачу, чтобы начать что-то новое.

У меня есть разные списки, в переходе от первого списка (главное активти) я передаю интентом текущую позицию (или id) и отображаю новый список по номеру этого пункта. Если я перейду к новому списку, и заблокирую устройство (не знаю точное время, примерно пол часа), а потом разблокирую, приложение падает, так как система уничтожила стек перехода, и передаваемое через `putExtra` значение аннулировано. Гугл предлагает `alwaysRetainTaskState`:

> Если для этого атрибута установлено значение "true" в корневой операции задачи, описанное выше поведение по умолчанию не происходит. Задача восстанавливает все операции в своем стеке даже по истечении длительного периода времени.

И теперь я во всех активити, к которым реализован переход, включил `alwaysRetainTaskState`. Вопрос: Не повлияет ли это на производительность приложений, и не появятся ли с этим новые подводные камни? И вообще, правильным ли подходом является передача текущей позиции из списка по клику на пункт, чтобы в новом окне по номеру это позиции отображать другой список, или есть другие, более правильные решения?